# What would cause a video card to show everything on the screen in one color (blue)?

Tags: graphics-card, repair, diagnostic

I recently tried to upgrade to a better video card, and after putting it into my computer and installing the proper drivers, everything on my screen shows up blue... Not the blue screen of death, just different shades of blue. Could this be something wrong with the card itself, or is there a way to fix the issue?

Comment: what about BIOS?  is that blue too?

Comment: Sounds like either a bad connection in general, a bad cable, or bad hardware.  Check the first two before spending money to replace hardware.  You should also check a different monitor if possible.

Comment: Most of the time when I see this, it's because of bad connectors or cable. Make sure your signal cable (VGA / DVI / HDMI) is seated properly on your monitor and video card. Also, have you tried any fixes already?

Comment: @Keltari Yes the BIOS is blue as well

Comment: Definitely hardware then.  Try different monitors/cables.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that any and every screen is blue, it sounds like a problem with the connectors/pins for the cable. Disconnect at both the computer and monitor end and check for any bent pins. I remember seeing this issue with the old VGA cables.

Answer (score 4):

I would try the following in order until the problem is resolved:

1. Test reseating or replacing cable to monitor.
2. Check the pins inside the connector for your video card. If they are bent, carefully use tweezers to bend them straight.
3. Test monitor on different system and/or replace as needed.
4. Make sure latest drivers for video card are installed.
5. Reseat video card or move to different expansion slot if available.
6. Replace video card. In your case, exchange it as it is defective.